# When marathon restarts process, possible to pass different command-line flag?

Tags: marathon

I notice that when I am running a process under marathon and I restart it, the process automatically starts back up. The way the logic of the process works, if it is restarted, it enters a recovery mode where it tries to replay its state. The recovery mode is entered when a command-line flag is seen, such as "-r". I want to append this flag to cmd command that is initially used during startup in marathon. Is there an option somewhere in marathon for this capability?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by using event subscriber in marathon. By using PUT with curl rather than POST, you are able to modify a deployment rather than recreating a brand new one with POST.